# Swift Download Data to Local Storage on First App Launch

Tags: swift, database, urlsession

I know this is kind of a general question, but I'm not sure the best way to go about this.

I want to create an app that downloads data the first time you launch the app (or download the app), so that for future uses, the user could use all of the data offline.

I'd prefer to not have all the information hard-coded into Model files if possible - I just want to end up reading from a separate file / making a web request / something similar to this, and store it somewhere the user can access it.

Thanks a lot

Comment: Why don't you add a file to your project that contains the data and then read it when you load the app?

Answer (score 0):

where does this data stored now and how often does it change?

If it changes frequently, you're better off making a GET request from your server and downloading it on start.

If it it won't ever change, or very rarely, such as a list of zip codes, then you could just include it with your app and read from it in `applicationDidFinishLaunching` or preferably in the class that needs the data's `viewDidLoad()` method.

If you don't want to parse it into model objects, hopefully the data is in JSON format and isn't too large.  Then you could just store it in memory I suppose and directly read from a JSON object.